# Simple Java Method?

Tags: java

Ok so I need to make a program in java that is basically a random number generator and the player needs to guess what number was generated, from 1-10.

***I already got the code and everything works perfectly fine (Code is posted below) but I want to make it so that the user cannot use the same number twice.***

Like say for instance the player enters 2 then 3 then 2 again. I want it to 
return "You have already entered this number" For the life of me I could not get this to work.

I've been trying with HashSets because I'm fairly certain that that method is the correct method to do it but I get tricked up when it comes to recalling the numbers that are already in the HashSet and if they are in the HashSet already then return "You have already entered this number".

I tried tinkering with

```
if (hs.contains(guess)) == true) 
System.out.println("You have already entered this number")
```

and I also put `hs.add(guess)` and guess being what number the player has entered. I'm really stumped and if you guys could guide me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.
Many thanks in advanced

```
package guessgame;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<Integer>hs = new HashSet();
        int GuessLogic;
        GuessLogic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int guess;
        int NumGuess;
        NumGuess = 1;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess);
            if (guess == GuessLogic)
                System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of Guesses: " + NumGuess++);
            else if (guess < GuessLogic && guess > 0)
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Higher, Guess number: " + NumGuess++);
            else if (guess > GuessLogic && guess <= 10)
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Lower, Guess number: " + NumGuess++); 
            else
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. Please try again." ); 
        } while (guess != GuessLogic);

    }   

}
```

Comment: Just store the number in an array when they enter it. Every time they enter a new one, iterate over the array to see if it is already there. If so, print your error message, otherwise continue with the game.

Comment: @Martinn no need to iterate if a `boolean[]` is used vice an `int[]`. @Serph see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full version (rewritten a little).

You may want to move around `NumGuess++` to wherever you want to increment the number of guesses. It seemed appropriate to put it immediately after a guess, but you may not want to increment if the Set already contains the number.

Also, moving out the range check makes the code a little cleaner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
    int GuessLogic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    int guess;
    int NumGuess = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        NumGuess++;

        if (hs.contains(guess)) {
            System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
            continue; // this will repeat the loop
        }

        if (guess < 0 || guess > 10) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. Please try again.");
            continue; // this will repeat the loop
        }

        System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess);
        if (guess == GuessLogic) {
            System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of Guesses: " + NumGuess);
            return; // this will stop the method
        }
        else if (guess < GuessLogic) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Higher, Guess number: " + NumGuess);
        }
        else if (guess > GuessLogic) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Lower, Guess number: " + NumGuess);
        }

        hs.add(guess);

    } while (true);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should *program to the interface* [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (instead of the concrete type `HashSet`). Next, you can use [`Set.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) which returns *`true` if this set did not already contain the specified element*. Finally, I would recommend using meaningful variable names. Putting that together, it might look something like,

```
Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
int correctNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int guessCount = 1;
int guess;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess);
    if (hs.add(guess)) {
        if (guess == correctNumber) {
            System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of "
                    + "Guesses: " + guessCount++);
        } else if (guess < correctNumber && guess > 0) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess "
                    + "Higher, Guess number: " + guessCount++);
        } else if (guess > correctNumber && guess <= 10) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess "
                    + "Lower, Guess number: " + guessCount++);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. "
                    + "Please try again.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
    }
} while (guess != correctNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got it to compile and I realized what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashSet`. The `add` function returns false if it already contains that object:

```
Set<Integer> guesses = new HashSet<Integer>();
if (guesses.add(guess)) {
    //Code for their new guess
} else {
    System.out.println("You have already guessed this number!");
}
```

Comment: yeah, this logic is better

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following code:

```
package guessgame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<>(); // Arraylist preferrable to HashSet, but not required
        int GuessLogic;
        GuessLogic = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        int NumGuess;
        NumGuess = 1;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (guesses.contains(guess)) { // If the player has already guessed the number
                System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
                continue; // Skips to the next loop iteration
            }
            guesses.add(guess); // ONLY does this if ^ evaluates to false
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess);
            if (guess == GuessLogic)
                System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of Guesses: " + NumGuess++);
            else if (guess < GuessLogic && guess > 0)
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Higher, Guess number: " + NumGuess++);
            else if (guess > GuessLogic && guess <= 10)
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Lower, Guess number: " + NumGuess++); 
            else
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. Please try again." ); 
        } while (guess != GuessLogic);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a small range of values, you can get away with just using a `boolean` array:

```
int minRngVal = 1;
int maxRngVal = 10;
boolean[] guesses = new boolean[maxRngVal];
```

When the player guesses a number, send it to a method like the following one:

```
private boolean isValidGuess(int guess){
    if(guesses[guess-1] == true){
        //player already guessed that number!
        return false;
    } else{
        //player hasn't guessed that number yet
        guesses[guess-1] = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then just add the following line to your code:

```
if (isValidGuess(guess)) {
    System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
    continue; // this will repeat the loop
}
```