# Java classes and calling variables in other classes

Tags: java, class

I'm still fairly new in java programming and I've gotten some aspects down but the classes within Java are by far giving me the most trouble. What I'm trying to do is make a random number game where the player has to pick a number 1 through 10 and if it's wrong then try again and have the program record how many times they guessed (but not add to the number of guess when a number has been picked previously or if the number that was picked is outside the specified range) I have already worked out the logic code and was trying to make a class specifically for just the logic and a class that is specifically just for the I/O interface. But I'm having one heck of a time. Any input or tips will be very appreciated and I will provide the code that I already have below:

This is the Logic class where I want it to handle all the logic

```
package guessapp;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GuessLogic {
    public static int Logic() {
        HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
        int GuessLogic = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int A;
        int guess;
        int NumGuess = 1;
        do {
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (hs.contains(guess)) {
                A = 1;
                return A;
            }
            if (guess < 0 || guess > 10) {
                A = 2;
                return A;
            }
            if (guess == GuessLogic) {
                A = 3;
                return A; // this will stop the loop
            } else if (guess < GuessLogic) {
                NumGuess++;
                A = 4;
                return A; 
            } else if (guess > GuessLogic) {
                NumGuess++;
                A = 5;
                return A;
            }
            hs.add(guess);
        } while (true);
    }

    public static int getGuess() {
        int guess;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        return guess;
    }
}
```

And this is the class I want to handle all I/O interface

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r, w, y;
        r = GuessLogic.Logic();
        w = GuessLogic.getGuess();
        int NumGuess;
        NumGuess = 2;
        System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
        if (r == 1) {
            System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
        }
        if (r == 2) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. Please try again.");
        }
        System.out.println("Your guess is " + w);
        if (r == 3) {
            System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of Guesses: " + NumGuess);
        } else if (r == 4) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Higher, Guess number: " + NumGuess);
        } else if (r == 5) {
            System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Lower, Guess number: " + NumGuess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, specifically `return A, NumGuess;` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suggest using ad IDE if you are not. It would tell you about the compile time errors with a description which you can look into to find answers.

Comment: I knew that code comment looked suspiciously familiar...  You should accept answers on your previous posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787303/simple-java-method

Answer (score 0):

Below is the modified codes. There are some general ideas:

1. `GuessLogic` should be used as an instance rather than a static class. Because you need `GuessLogic` to save the operations and the target number.
2. The while loop should be coded in `main`. Because `GuessLogic` is responsible for logic **only**.
3. The elements is `Set` is unique, so there is no need to count how many different number by yourself.

GuessApp:

```
public class GuessApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r, w, y;
        GuessLogic guessLogic = new GuessLogic();
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
            w = guessLogic.getGuess();
            r = guessLogic.Logic(); 

            if (r == 1) {
                System.out.println("You have already entered this number");
                continue;
            }

            if (r == 2) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of the specified range. Please try again.");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Your guess is " + w);
            if (r == 3) {
                System.out.println("You got it right!! Congrats!! Total Number of Guesses: " + guessLogic.getNumber());
                break;
            } else if (r == 4) {
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Higher, Guess number: " + guessLogic.getNumber());
            } else if (r == 5) {
                System.out.println("You are wrong!!! Hint: Guess Lower, Guess number: " + guessLogic.getNumber());
        }
        }
    }
}
```

GuessLogic:

```
public class GuessLogic {
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);    

    public int getNumber(){
        return hs.size();
    }   

    public int Logic(int guess) {
        if (hs.contains(guess)) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 10) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (guess == number) {
            return 3; // this will stop the loop
        } else if (guess < number) {
            // just add to the set. The set will guarantee that there is no repetitive item.
            hs.add(guess);
            return 4; 
        } else if (guess > number) {
            hs.add(guess);
            return 5;
        }
        return -1;
    }   

    public int getGuess() {
        int guess;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        return guess;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an `int GuessLogic` with the same name as the class. This won't currently compile. Please make variables and methods camelCased